# Flutter Globals losing their value

Tags: dart, flutter, global-variables

Okay, I am sure this is probably an easy to answer question, but after much searching I can't put my finger on the solution.

How does one in Flutter/Dart create a variable in app XYZ that maintains its' value during the time a user moves away from the app, uses another app, allows the phone to go to sleep, etc., then opens the XYZ app again.

I've created a tiny little app that demonstrates the issue as shown below.

The static variable Globals.UID can be incremented upwards, but if the app is moved away from (what term describes using another app correctly?) then as noted the phone goes to sleep, when the user comes back to the app the Globals.UID variable is reset back to -1.

Sometimes the reset is not immediate and I have to let the IOS phone sleep for perhaps 5 minutes to recreate the behavior.

Basically I need Globals.UID to retain its' value until the app is actually exited.

Any insight would truly be appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:test_flutter/Globals.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;

      Globals.UID ++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            Text ( "Global variable is:")
            , Text ( Globals.UID.toString() )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And in a different file called Globals.dart

```
class Globals {

  static int    UID = -1;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried creating a singleton class instance?

Comment: Not yet, but I will give that a try.  If it works please come back and suggest it as an answer, rather than in the comments section, so I can credit you with the correct answer.

Comment: I am sad to report that a singleton does not appear to fix the problem.  Thank you for the excellent suggestion.  I was thinking it stood a good chance.   If anyone has an implementation of a singleton that does work please I would love to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, the solution appears to be solved mostly by using the shared_preferences library.  That solution brings with it a good many documented problems, but to maintain data while the app is placed in the background, or even killed by perhaps the user, shared_preferences appears to be the way to go.

Comment: Yes indeed - you should not be too shy and accept your own answer. This is a good reference among others https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127

Comment: There is also localstorage package as an alternative https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Actually this happens to when you don't import with reference. This is a known issues which is already fixed, may be not landed yet. You can check the issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15748).

Please try `import package_name/globals.dart` instead of just `import globals.dart` if you are doing so.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have tried both ways, does not work as of March 22, 2019 and the version I have.  I have seen references to what you are scything thus have already done the testing.  Unless you mean lowercase globals.dart instead of Globals.dart.  

I will test the lowercase version and see if that helps.